# JSP throwing 500 error when reading ELSE statement

Tags: jsp, if-statement, jakarta-ee

If my array has items in it the for loop executes fine but if it's empty and goes to the else I get a null pointer HTTP 500 error...what am I doing wrong?

```
<% out.print("<ul>");

         if(p.getToppings().length != 0) {    
        for (int x = 0; x < p.getToppings().length; x++) { 
        out.print("<li>");
            out.print(p.getToppings()[x]); 
            out.print("<br>");


        out.print("</li>");

        }

        } else {
        out.print("No Toppings"); 
        } %>
```

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /test2DisplayOrder.jsp at line 18

15:<% model.PizzaOrder p = (model.PizzaOrder) request.getAttribute("p"); %>
16:

Hello

<% out.print(p.getName()); %> 
17:
18:<%out.print(p.getPhone()+ " Total $" + p.getPrice()); %>
19:
20:
21:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the line:

```
    if(p.getToppings().length != 0)
```

to:

```
    if(p != null && p.getToppings() != null && p.getToppings().length != 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion ...sadly I am still getting an error. I pasted it above.

Answer (score 0):

I had to re-adjust my model class to also test for if the getToppings() array was null or empty before calculating the price...hence the exception on line 18.